# ASP .NET 7 run static HTML file with scripts

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, .net

I am trying to return `html` file from my ASP NET 7 app. In that html files i am calling couple of scripts. Html file and scripts exist in same `root` directory:

```
using Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

// middleware
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    var html = await File.ReadAllTextAsync("index.html");

    context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";

    await context.Response.WriteAsync(html);

    await next();
});

app.Run();
```

The problem is, that `scripts` are loaded with `Content-Type: text/html` instead of `application/javascript`:

[image]

My question is, how to call only `.js` file extensions with diffrent `content type` using ASP .NET?

Comment: Right now you are always returning your `index.html` for every request, even for the scripts. You should look into using the `StaticFileMiddleware` instead which will handle this for you.

Comment: Thanks, i will take a look! In a meantime can you produce an answer ?

Comment: Try to call "app.UseStaticFiles();" just before you code https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your middleware is currently answering every request with the `index.html` content. So, it doesn't matter if you are requesting the path `/index.html` or the path `/script.js`, the server will always respond with your HTML file.

If you only need to provide static files (like your HTML and JS files), you can do it by just adding the official static file provider middleware to your Startup:

```
using Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseStaticFiles()  // Static file provider

app.Run();
```

This will return every file included in the `/wwwroot` folder in the root of the project. So, if you want to return the `index.html` and all the related JS files, just move them to the `/wwwroot` directory and make a request to the path `/index.html`.

More information on the official Microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: yup, i did that and it worked. The only thing you need to do to put your `script.js` files into `wwwroot` folder, use `UseStaticFiles` extension and then everything works fine